# How to get joint position limits in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, c++, gz-sim

How can I get the joint position limits in (the new) Gazebo? From the [migration guide](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/migrationjointapi.html) for the Joint API it is listed that the corresponding methods from Gazebo classic are TODO, so I imagine the ECM should be used to get them, but I cannot find anywhere a guide on how to use this pattern properly. How to do this?

Answer (score 1):

After doing a quick glance at the Gazebo API, it does not look like they provide this (yet). All joint related stuff that is used with ECM can be found [here](https://gazebosim.org/api/sim/8/namespacegz_1_1sim_1_1components.html). It does not appear to have any option for getting the position limit, as far as I am aware.